# Replacing the last 5 characters of url after input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the last few characters in a image src. I've tried going down the php route and it isn't really working because of the way my news feed plugin is setup.

Currently this is my feed template

```
<div class="hungryfeed_item col-md-4 col-sm-4 content-box-col">
    <div class="content-box-sub">
        <div class="content-box-img-block">
            <a href="{{permalink}}"><img src="{{enclosure}}" alt="" class="img-responsive" /></a>
        </div>
        <label><a href="{{permalink}}">{{title}}</a></label>
        <p>{{description}}
        <p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When `{{enclosure}}` inputs the img url it picks up a thumbnail, which unfortunately is 70x50. However the news source does upload a 762x428 version which would be much more adequate for my needs.

For example

> thumbnail: rtx1k5pv-1-70x50.jpg
>
> full res: rtx1k5pv-1-762x428.jpg

Is it possible with javascript to change the last 5 characters **(70x50)** and replace them with **762x428** ?

Comment: This isn't native JavaScript. Please use any appropriate tags related to whatever language `{{enclosure}}` is generated by.

Comment: That doesn't in any way affect the answer to the question because he could use client-side JavaScript to handle replacing the `img` `src` attribute, and the value of the attribute wouldn't be `{{enclosure}` at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes just use `replace()`:

```
var text = "rtx1k5pv-1-70x50.jpg";
text = text.replace("70x50","762x428");

// text changed to: "rtx1k5pv-1-762x428.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use regular expressions for it:

```
fullRes = "rtx1k5pv-1-70x50.jpg".replace(/[0-9]+x[0-9]+/, '762x428')
```